# How can I incement a variable inside foreach

Tags: php

I have 2 foreachs, one inside the other.

In the second one, I'm trying to increment a variable.. But it is being reseted in each loop...

Check it out...

```
$i2 = 0;
foreach($result as $line) {
   echo "Foreach begins. i2 =".$i2; // Foreach begins. i2 = 0
   $i2++;
   echo "i2 incremented. i2 =".$i2; // i2 incremented. i2 = 1
}
```

But the loop result shows me this text:

```
Foreach begins. i2 = 0
i2 incremented. i2 = 1

Foreach begins. i2 = 0
i2 incremented. i2 = 1
```

I'm trying to get:

```
Foreach begins. i2 = 0
i2 incremented. i2 = 1

Foreach begins. i2 = 1
i2 incremented. i2 = 2
```

What's wrong?

Comment: I only see ***one*** loop.

Comment: $result is an array with 2 values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume you have that loop inside another one that looks this this:

```
foreach($thing as $result) {
    $i2 = 0;
    foreach($result as $line) {
         echo "Foreach begins. i2 =".$i2; // Foreach begins. i2 = 0
         $i2++;
         echo "i2 incremented. i2 =".$i2; // i2 incremented. i2 = 1
    }
}
```

Your issue is that in each loop of the original (first) `foreach()`, you're resetting the `$i2` variable.

Simply move that variable out of the first `foreach()` scope and it should work:

```
$i2 = 0;
foreach($thing as $result) {
    foreach($result as $line) {
         echo "Foreach begins. i2 =".$i2; // Foreach begins. i2 = 0
         $i2++;
         echo "i2 incremented. i2 =".$i2; // i2 incremented. i2 = 1
    }
}
```

[**`Example`**](https://eval.in/279090)

Comment: Man. Thanks a lot! I'm a newbie.. You got it! Problem fixed! I'll set your answer as the best as soon as possible! (4 minutes)

Comment: My pleasure @MarceloBarganha, we've all been there before! :)

Comment: @MarceloBarganha - Your question was very unclear since you didn't add the actual code for the second `foreach()` loop. You should edit your question and add this information to your OP.

Answer (score 1):

Simply initialize the $i2 variable outside of the foreach loop and that's it.

Like this:

```
 $i2 = 0;
 foreach(){
      foreach(){
         $i2++;
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason you are using the second for each loop? If all you are trying to do with the second loop is to increment some numbers then perhaps it should be a for loop with a for each inside of it like noted here [for each loop inside of for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28299154/str-replace-in-post-content-with-increment-value-using-php?answertab=active#tab-top)

Comment: This is a comment, not an answer.

Comment: a comment must be posted as an answer when you can not make a comment, stating the obvious though is just immature.